# selection not working in reyclerview item in android

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, android-adapter, android-listadapter

Hey I am working in reyclerview selection. When first reyclerview load I want to show default selection then after I click then show selected item selection. But it's not working. Default selection is working, but after clicking on other item it's not selecting the item.

**MainActivity.kt**

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        val selectionAdapter = SelectionAdapter()
        selectionAdapter.submitList(createList())
        binding.recyclerView.apply {
            layoutManager =
                LinearLayoutManager(this@MainActivity, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false)
            adapter = selectionAdapter
        }
    }

    private fun createList(): List<Data> {
        return listOf(
            Data("1"),
            Data("2"),
            Data("3", true),
            Data("4"),
        )
    }

    data class Data(
        val value: String? = null,
        val defaultValue: Boolean? = null
    )
}
```

**SelectionAdapter.kt**

```
class SelectionAdapter :
ListAdapter<MainActivity.Data, SelectionAdapter.SelectionViewHolder>(COMPARATOR) {

var selectedItemPosition: Int = 0
    set(value) {
        val oldPosition = field
        field = value
        notifyItemChanged(oldPosition)
        notifyItemChanged(value)
    }

companion object {
    private val COMPARATOR = object : DiffUtil.ItemCallback<MainActivity.Data>() {
        override fun areItemsTheSame(
            oldItem: MainActivity.Data,
            newItem: MainActivity.Data
        ): Boolean {
            return true
        }

        override fun areContentsTheSame(
            oldItem: MainActivity.Data,
            newItem: MainActivity.Data
        ): Boolean {
            return true
        }
    }
}

override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): SelectionViewHolder {
    return SelectionViewHolder(
        SelectionItemLayoutBinding.inflate(
            LayoutInflater.from(parent.context),
            parent,
            false
        )
    )
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: SelectionViewHolder, position: Int) {
    holder.binding.root.setOnClickListener {
        selectedItemPosition = holder.adapterPosition
        holder.binding.root.isSelected = selectedItemPosition == position
    }
    holder.bindItem(getItem(position))
}

inner class SelectionViewHolder(val binding: SelectionItemLayoutBinding) :
    RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {

    fun bindItem(item: MainActivity.Data) {

        binding.textView.text = item.value

        binding.root.isSelected = item.defaultValue == true
        
    }
}
```

}

**selection_item_layout.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:background="@drawable/options_item_selector_background"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:text="1"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**mainactivity.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**options_item_default_background.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <stroke
        android:width="1dp"
        android:color="#D8DFED" />
    <corners android:radius="1dp" />
</shape>
```

**options_item_selector_background.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/options_item_selected_background" android:state_pressed="false" android:state_selected="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/options_item_default_background" android:state_selected="false" />
</selector>
```

**options_item_selected_background.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <stroke
        android:width="1dp"
        android:color="#213F66" />
    <corners android:radius="1.5dp" />
</shape>
```

I am posting my video [link](https://youtube.com/shorts/LllfgTwuGpc?feature=share)

Comment: What is `defaultValue` supposed to represent? Is it supposed to mean that item is selected? Your adapter makes no attempt to modify this value in the backing data, and it makes no attempt to use `selectedItemPosition` whatsoever.

Comment: @Tenfour04 `defaultValue` means when first time reyclerview load data, the position in which value `true` is default selected. Then whenever user select the other positions it will select that one and deselect the previous one.

Comment: @Tenfour04 all the time I want one item to be selected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your adapter never reads from `selectedItemPosition`, so how could it ever change which item is shown as selected?

By using the `defaultValue` from the list items every time you bind the items, they will never be able to change either.

To simplify this, let your adapter treat `selectedItemPosition` as the single source of truth about what should be selected. The Activity should tell it which item to start with:

```
val selectionAdapter = SelectionAdapter()
val list = createList()
selectionAdapter.selectedItemPosition = list.indexOfFirst { it.defaultValue == true }
selectionAdapter.submitList(list)
```

Your adapter should exclusively use `selectedItemPosition` as its source for whether an item should appear selected. And the click listener only needs to change the selected item. It's pointless to have it change the item's appearance manually because this can only briefly change how it looks until the next time the view holder is bound.

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: SelectionViewHolder, position: Int) {
    holder.binding.root.setOnClickListener {
        selectedItemPosition = holder.adapterPosition
    }
    holder.bindItem(getItem(position), selectedItemPosition == position)
}

inner class SelectionViewHolder(val binding: SelectionItemLayoutBinding) :
    RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {

    fun bindItem(item: MainActivity.Data, isSelected: Boolean) = with(binding) {
        textView.text = item.value
        root.isSelected = isSelected
    }
}
```

Comment: Cheers. Is this other question still relevant, or can you close it? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71186923/how-to-use-default-selection-in-recyclerview-android-kotlin I realized the other day when you were having trouble changing `selectedItemPosition` from inside the `onBindView` and I suggested doing it in `submitList()` by overriding it, it might make more sense to do it in `onListChanged()`, because I think this is called after the DiffUtil has finished its background work.

Comment: no worries, got it.

Comment: can you tell me How can I do `onCurrentListChanged()` inside this function?